# Can apache logs tell between encryped and un-encrypted traffic?

Tags: apache, logging, apache-log-files

Is there a way by just looking at the apache logs you can tell if the user-credentials is encrypted or not? Meaning some kind of encryption e.g ssl or plain-text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually no indication in an apache access log that the request was served over https instead of http.

If you want to log the protocol, you can follow the instructions in the accepted answer of this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/359476/how-to-log-the-url-scheme-http-https-in-apache

Comment: what about the user who logged not using https?

Comment: I want to alert on someone logging on http protocol?

Comment: Are you asking about the login process for your site?  If you started logging the protocol to your log files, you could see when a user used the url of your login process without https.

Comment: how? the answer link you showed only refers to the case when https is used. You saying that activity would be seen in non-http e.g access log.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding what you are asking.  It sounds to me that you have a site that supports both http and https and are trying to discover if users are using insecure login.  If this isn't correct, please edit your question to clarify.